# MSI unattended install. How to auto-answer error pop-up

Tags: windows-installer

I am trying to create a batch file for an unattended uninstall for a MSI file.  However, there is an error message that populates and the program auto-selects No or zero which then ends the installation.  When looking into the log file, I do see the message box show the return value of zero instead of 1.  It does not seem to be a property value.  I added the ONLYINI="yes" to my msiexec command line but this did not resolve the issue.  I'll paste a few lines of the log file.

> Nuance [12:32:45]: MsiUtil::GetPropertyStr  The value of
>   SSID_PROD_DEACT_ERROR property is %s could not be deactivated in
>   preparation for the uninstall process. Only a limited number of
>   activations without deactivation is allowed. Do you want to continue
>   with uninstallation?
>
> Nuance [12:32:45]: MsiUtil::GetPropertyStr function end.  Return value: 0
>
> Nuance [12:32:45]: MsiUtil::GetPropertyStr function start.
>
> Nuance [12:32:45]: MsiUtil::GetPropertyStr  The value of ProductName property is eCopy PDF Pro Office 6

I am actually using an uninstall string found in the registry.  The command line looks something like the following;

MsiExec.exe /X{478806C9-7D83-41BE-9744-7FB2D7573E00} /qn /norestart /l* "log location.log" ONLYINI="yes"

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably explain how MsiUtil, and Nuance are involved because you appear to have posted the part of a windows installer log as it relates to (most likely) a custom action. Those messages relating to activations are not standard Windows Installer functions. It's not even clear that SSID_PROD_DEACT_ERROR is a property that is supposed to be passed on a command line - maybe it's from the registry or some other place. You may need to be talking to Nuance about how it all works.

Comment: You are actually correct.  My apologies.  I am using an uninstall string found in the registry.  Nuance is just a PDF viewiing/editing software.  The value, I think, for SSID_PROD_DEACT_ERROR is %s from what I can gather.  I to am unaware of what this actually means.  However, if I just uninstall this program from Control Panel > Remove programs, I get that Message prompted on the first line; "The value of ... Do you want to continue with uninstallation?"  I would like to find a way to automate this portion to select Yes.